# FormData is empty or None in Django Views

Tags: django, ajax, form-data

How to properly get FormData values in Django 1.8?
Clearly, it has a data as i tried viewing it on the console but somehow unable to access it via Django view.
Here's my client side code:

```
reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
  var imgsrc = reader.result;
  storedFiles.push(imgsrc);
  var html = "<div class=\"col text-center\"><img src=\"" + imgsrc + "\" data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-fluid selFile' title='Click to remove'><br/>" + i + "</div>";
  selDiv.append(html);
  //call extract text

  var formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append("image", imgsrc);
  console.log(formdata.get("image"));
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "GET",
    data: formdata,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",
    url: "/scan/scanner",
    beforeSend: function() {

    },
    success: function(response) {
      var parseResp = JSON.parse(response);
      $("#extracted_text").append(parseResp.extracted_txt);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      alert(e.statusText);
    }
  });
}, false);
```

and a simple view in Django:

```
def callWebScanner(request):
    print 'Django View'
    imgstring = request.FILES.get("image")
    print imgstring
```

Comment: It looks like you are making a GET request to the server. GET requests do not send data. You need to make a POST or PUT request.

Comment: Oh..thanks! Now, it would output incorrect padding.

Comment: Why isn't your Django view returning anything?

Comment: It's just a snippet..

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve by doing the following:

1. set the request type to `POST`
   This causes a csrf token error in Django, I had to add `@csrf_exempt` decorator on my views.
2. Pass a blob instead of the base64 string on data value

> ```
> var formdata = new FormData();    
> formdata.append("image", blob, "File" + i);
> ```

3. Read it on view like this: `blob = request.FILES['image']`. You can then save the image on the directory assigned on `MEDIA_ROOT`:

> ```
> blob = request.FILES['image']
> unique_id = get_random_string(length=16)
> filename = unique_id+'.PNG'
> default_storage.save(filename, ContentFile(blob.read()))
> scanned_img = default_storage.path(filename)
> print scanned_img
> ```